# Does `setInterval` prevents user from typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made chat system in my web application.
It's basic chat with input field with messages.

I only wrapped messages_section then I'm using `setInterval` to load it partially and every 1 sec.
However, I found weird behaivor here.

When I'm typing something into input field, typed words get entered somehow when every time `setInterval` is loaded.

Now it seems that this is only affecting to browsing with FireFox:(

I was supposing `setInterval` wouldn't affect to input field unless input field is set within

These are my codes. I want to know why and how to fix

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            refreshPartial();
            setInterval(refreshPartial, 1000)
        });

        function refreshPartial() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/communities/setinterval_part?page=",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "script",
          });
        }
//]]>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/communities/new_comments" class="new_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_comment" method="post">
      <input class="chat" id="input" name="comment[body]" type="text" />  
      <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
  <form>

  <span id="messages_section">
       here comes messages!
  </span>
```

**setinterval_part.js.erb**

```
$('#messages_section').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'communities/comment')) %>");
<% if @post %>$('#body_input').val('');<% end %>
```

**communities_controller.rb**

```
def setinterval_part
        @comments = @community.comment_threads.order("updated_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(@number_of_comments_to_display)
        @comment = @community.comment_threads.build

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I recommend you do not use setInterval in this case. What if your server will take more than 1 second to answer to client? I think that you can run `refreshPartial()` function right from your `setinterval_part.js.erb`.

So you need to make this changes to JS-part in the view:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  refreshPartial();
});

function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/communities/setinterval_part?page=",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
  });
}
```

And this to `setinterval_part.js.erb`:

```
$('#messages_section').html("<%= j(render(:partial => 'communities/comment')) %>");
<% if @post %>$('#body_input').val('');<% end %>
<% timeout_ms = 1000 %>
<% # some code that can determine current load of your server and increase timeout_ms %>
setTimeout(refreshPartial, <%= timeout_ms %>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you mean I have to give up on setInterval? I just wanted to make it like chat system. Messagges pops up automatically while the user just sit and he's seeing PC screen.

Comment: My variant will do the same, because it will run refreshPartial() again and again right after getting fresh messages. Also it can eventually DDoS your web server, so I think you may add setTimeout() right to setinterval_part.js.erb (I'll update my answer to show this)

Comment: Thanks for precious information:) what about Line 4? Can I leave it blank? and your code will work fine?

Comment: @SurgeryKuznetsov Thanks!! Please let me make sure what you wanted to say to me. My previous code allows user to keep requesting even if server is full-accessed and unable to response. But your code will give up accessing when the server didn't response back. Is my understanding okay?

Comment: One more comment: I've made a small fix to my answer - check 5th line of setinterval_part.js.erb - I removed parentheses from refreshPartial in setTimeout:
setTimeout(refreshPartial, <%= timeout_ms %>);

Comment: Yes, my variant will not attempt to check server availability, it's pretty forward and simple. If you need to make a good chat system you need to create a more complex code than you have.

Comment: Please help me!!!! I was thinking it was working fine. But what it was doing is loading refreshPartial as loop continuously:( even If I wrote <% timeout_ms = 10000 %> it won't call refreshPartial every 10secs. Now it just reload as fast as possible continiously:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23628/discussion-between-sergey-kuznetsov-and-foo)